# Flutter Provider across multiple views and inside other providers

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, state-management

Flutter newbie here, I'm currently using Provider for my state management and had a few questions as to how it actually works.

I am declaring my providers like this...

*main.dart*

```
runApp(
  MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ProviderFoo>(create: (_) => ProviderA(),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ProviderBar>(create: (_) => ProviderB(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Both ProviderFoo and ProviderBar classes extend ChangeNotifier.

**Question 1:**

If I have 2 different views and I need to use FooProvider on both of the views as so

*widget1.dart*

```
var providerOneFoo = Provider.of<FooProvider>(context);
```

*widget2.dart*

```
var providerTwoFoo = Provider.of<FooProvider>(context);
```

Is providerOneFoo the same as providerTwoFoo even if they are on two separate files? Is the Provider.of creating a new instance of the provider or just referencing the global instance that was set at the top of the widget tree where we declared them in MultiProviders?

**Question 2:**

Is there any design flaw if I pass in a provider as a parameter for a function in another provider?

*widget1.dart*

```
var fooProvider = Provider.of<FooProvider>(context);
var barProvider = Provider.of<BarProvider>(context);

fooProvider.someFunction(barProvider);
```

*provider_foo.dart*

```
class FooProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  ...
  void someFunction(barProvider) {
    barProvider.someVar = 0;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

If that is possible, can I make an external provider an attribute of another provider?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question 1

---

Using `Provider<ProviderClass>.of(context)` always references the same global provider provided (No pun intended)

#### Question 2

---

It would be better to implement the method on `providerBar` and call `notifyListeners()` from it.

In your example, calling `notifyListeners()` in `FooProvider` **will only notify listners of FooProvider**.

If some widget depended on `BarProvider`, in your example, it would not be notified of the change to `barProvider.someVar`